# allow only QWidget sizes divisible by a specific value

Tags: c++, qt, widget

I am drawing a grid in my QWidget derived widget, i would like to ensure that the widget only gets resized to a height that is divisible by the height of a cell in the grid, in this case 5, but for the purposes of the question any arbitrary value will do.

The widget exists as a child control of a QBoxLayout, i don't mind tackling this via the layout or inside the widget, I just can't find a way to do it.

Comment: That is not something that is supported by default. However you could implement it yourself by subclassing `QBoxLayout`, but the question then becomes: How do you ensure that the widget that contains the custom layout only grows with the same size increment so that it is possible to create such an arrangement in the first place?

Comment: I had a lightbulb moment and realised it was easier to handle internally in the widget and just draw up to the last cell, and leave the last few pixels as not drawn and allow the parent widgets background color to fill the space. Definitely one of those complexity vs pragmatism/readability moments!